# How to properly use getline in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to for loop a string and put it inside a map in C++ but for some reason, it keeps excluding `myMap[0]` and I can't output the first letter of my strings. Please help.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <string>
 #include <map>
 using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {

    int inputNumbers;
    map<int,string>myMap;

    cout<<"Enter how many words"<<endl;
    cin>>inputNumbers;
    //insert the words to the map
    for(int i = 0; i < inputNumbers; i++) {

        string inputNames ="";
        cout<<"Enter the word #"<<i+1<<" out of "<<inputNumbers<<endl;

        getline(cin, inputNames);
        myMap[i] = inputNames;

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
    }

    //output map
    for(map<int,string>::iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++)
        cout << it->first << ":" << it->second << endl;
    it->first << ":" << it->second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output

```
 Enter how many words
 4
 Enter the word #1 out of 4
 Kobe
 Enter the word #2 out of 4
 is
 Enter the word #3 out of 4
 the greatest
 Enter the word #4 out of 4
 ever!!!
 0:
 1:obe
 2:s
 3:he greatest
 Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Would also appreciate an extra tip that scans a user input string and output if  it is a string word (no whitespace), real word (only letters), goodword (letters and numbers), capword (begins with a capital letter), acronym (all caps string).

Comment: The only input in this code is the line that reads from `cin` into `inputNumbers`. There is nothing in the loop body that reads anything. In particular, despite the title of the question, there is no call of `getline()`. So, sure, the code only puts empty strings into the map. Instead of that `for` loop, try something like `while (i < inputNumbers && std::cin >> inputNames) { ... }`. (You'll have to move things around, because 'i' and `inputNames` and not in scope at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: im so sorry, I must have accidentally removed the getline command

Comment: `cin.ignore()`, as the name suggests, reads and ignores one character.

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer!!!!

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>
 using namespace std;

 string inputNames;

 int main()
 {   

     string line;
     vector<string> myVector;
     ifstream myTextFile("myText.txt");

     //stores the lines in file to myVector and pushes it back
     while (getline(myTextFile, line)) {
          //cout<<line<<endl;
          myVector.push_back(line);
     }

     //outputs what's inside the vector
     for(int i=0; i<myVector.size(); i++) {
        cout << i << ":" << myVector[i] << endl;
     }



 return 0;
 }
```